# Which Editor/IDE is used at Facebook

Tags: php, eclipse, facebook

I'm just wondering which Editor/IDE is used at Facebook, because of those reasons:

- When i'm looking at the videos on the facebook site, I see the most developers using a macbook for there work
- Facebook has a really big code base (I guess :) )

I mean, at my two screen workspace I'm using Eclipse for PHP/JS/etc. stuff. But on my 13" MacBook Pro, Eclipse simply needs too much space. I'm also rolling some "big" projects and in my opinion VIM has not anoth features (like intelligent code assist) for those.

I guess the developers at facebook use different IDEs and Editors, but I would really like to know which ones are used the most.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: This question gets a top position on Google for "facebook php editor". Too bad it has no answer to it.

Comment: According to https://www.quora.com/What-IDE-is-used-at-Facebook-for-PHP they use usual suspects: emacs, vim or Eclipse